# What is the difference between JNA and JNR

Tags: java, java-native-interface, terminology, jna, jnr

According to the image from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jvmls2013nutter-2013526.pdf)
[image]

both libraries work according to the same principle. But I believe that there is a difference between them. What is this difference?

Comment: At the bottom, it all comes to JNI. So, why not to use JNI ;) http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org

Comment: @Oo.oO: You don't need an extra build step and compilers for different platforms in your build pipeline when you can also just specify things in Java.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

JNA uses reflection to call native methods.

JNR generates bytecode in runtime only once therefore JNR works faster then JNA. See example of code generating [here](https://github.com/jnr/jnr-ffi/blob/cbfa16ecb1acaec38d594565cf495455b1c535fb/src/main/java/jnr/ffi/provider/jffi/AsmStructByReferenceFromNativeConverter.java)

Answer (score 2):

The presentation you linked gave part of the answer already - so just continue reading. E.g. on slide 26 and ff:

Why Not JNA?

- Preprocessor constants?
- Standard API sets out of the box
- C callbacks?
- Performance